# IPhone XCode Version 3.2.1

Tags: iphone

I downloaded and installed Version 3.2.1 of XCode.

On the top left dropdown, I can only see the option of building it in 3.12 and 3.13.

Any ideas one how to build it it 3.1?

Thanks,
Chris
digadesign is online now Report Post    Reply With Quote

Answer (score 0):

Check your project settings. From the Xcode menu Project -> Edit Project Settings. At the bottom of the general tab there is an option to set the base SDK for the project. You should be able to set 3.1 from there and it will then show up in the project.